# How to remove last two and first two characters from span element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm bit loww with css. How can i remove last two and first two characters from span element?

Here is my code.

```
<span class="text">[[Events]]</span>
```

I have to remove "[[" and "]]" symbols

Comment: Are you looking for a css-only answer or can it use JS as your question tags are showing ?

Comment: CSS or JS. Any one,

Answer (score 3):

With js and regex `^.{2}|.{2}$`

```js
var el = document.getElementById('text');

el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/^.{2}|.{2}$/g, '');
```

```html
<span id="text">[[Events]]</span>
```

---

If just to replace `[[` and `]]`:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('text');

el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/\[|\]/g, '');
```

```html
<span id="text">[[Events]]</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Remove(str, startIndex, count) {
    return str.substr(0, startIndex) + str.substr(startIndex + count);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    var txt=$('span.some-span').text();
    txt=Remove(txt, 0, 2);
    txt=Remove(txt, txt.length-2, 2);
    $('span.some-span').text(txt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class='some-span'>[[Events]]</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use slice function

```js
var y = document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0]['innerText'];
console.log(y.slice(2).slice(0,-2));
```

```html
<span class="text">[[Events]]</span>
```